# Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы"?

Tags: пунктуация

Установите приложение для iOS, чтобы получить больше функций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите приложение для iOS, чтобы получить больше функций.

Запятая перед *чтобы* нужна, потому что *чтобы получить больше функций* — это придаточное предложение цели.

Answer (score 1):

Не лучше ли поменять местами главное с придаточным? А то фраза получилась не русской, а английской. Калька с английского.

Comment: Так и сделаю...